# Update an array in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I am building up an array of products in rails. Which is working fine, but my question is...

Is there any way to update an item if it exists in the array already? So as I am looping through products, and the model is "TV-32D300B" I need to check the array to see if it exists, but it may only be a partial number like "TV-32D300" (minus the last letter).

If the is the case I want to be able to update that product with the correct details.

```
product = {
  name: product_name,
  url: product_url,
  modelnumber: product_modelnumber,
  category_id: category.id,
  group_id: category.group_id,
  image_url: image_url
}
```

I'm using the `include?` to add products to the array if a product doesn't already exist, so I am guessing I need to add a like condition to find the number.

```
unless products.include?(product)
  products << product
end
```

Comment: What if there are multiple items which match that number? Do you want to update each of them?

Comment: @Stefan I doubt I understand how is that possible. When the second one arises, it’s already been merged into the first one (assuming the order is valid and “submodels” come after “models,” or the check in my answer is tuned to find an intersection of strings.)

Comment: Basically, if the product TV-32D300B was to already exist, under TV-32D300 or TV-32D300B then that product should just update. It's unlikely that it would appear twice in a region.

Comment: Also, normally, the character B would change to say W but that would already be explicit. Then we could also fall back to check the colour that passed over

Comment: @mudasobwa not necessarily. You could add `TV-32D300B`, then `TV-32D300W` and finally have `TV-32D300`.

Comment: @Alan what are the naming rules / conventions? Is it always a single letter suffix?

Comment: @stefan, no the suffix can vary a lot between different products, so I've made a catch-all as much as I can. There are so many different model numbers out there haha if only all manufacturers stuck to a standard combination ;)

Comment: @Alan I would try to define a method which returns some kind of "base model identifier" and use a products hash (instead of an array) with that identifier as the key. Something like `products = { 'tv32d300' => { ... }, 'tv32d400' => { ... } }`.

Comment: @Stefan do you have any examples I could look at, please? Always up for making things faster and more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `products` is an array of hashes and what you call a model is a `product_name` held under `name` key in this hash, the following would do:

```
existing = products.find { |p| product[:name].include? p[:name] }
if existing
  # update existing
else
  products << product
end
```

More info on [`Enumerable#find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-find).

Comment: would this find the name if it's not an exact match?

Comment: Once `String#include?` is used, it would detect the first element in this array, that has a name _that is included/contained_ in the product’s name, as you wanted the longer to match the shorter, not vice versa.

Comment: awesome, Thank you I will give that a try.